# Angular Material & NGRX: mat-expansion-panels close when Input changes

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx

I am working on an Angular App using NGRX and the Angular Material Components for the UI.

One component uses mat-accordion to display a list of expansion panels. These expansion panels contain information and ways to manipulate these information.

When information is manipulated, an event is emited to the root component and an action is dispatched to the store, modifying the state. When the store fires these changes through the selectors, the root-component which subscribed to the store, passes the changes to the component containing the mat-accordion and with this the mat-expansion-panels.

**The Problem:** When changes are emitted all expansionpanels of the mat-accordion close. As the user should be  able to make further changes, this is a very big issue concerning user expirience.

**Edit 1:**
I set the expanded input of the expansion-panel to `true` with `<mat-expansion-panel [expaned]="true" ... >` and the behaviour changes to allways opening all expansion panels making any changes. Thereby i think the entire component seems to be recreated when the input changes. Maybe this happens because i subscribe at the component above and only pass in the new Data. Will have a look if i can change this by passing observables in the inputs.

**Edit 2:** I forked ibenjelloun's stackblitz app and added my 2 cents, an example that shows the not working behaviour: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49691295-qulg9d
I found out, that removing the line which mimics the ngrx behaviour it works, but with the breaking line also the example in the root component does not work (sucks, as that should be my: look, i don't try the impossible example). This suprises me a little as the app i am working on does also have an acordion setup the same way, but does work as intended.

Since this is work releated i can't show any of the original code causing the issues.

Comment: Please provide a stackbltiz example

Comment: Use the `<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="isExpanded">` to keep the state of the expanded panels

Comment: @ibenjelloun i guess with isExpanded you refer to a boolean held in the component.ts? I don't know how to apply this as my expansion panels in the acordion are generated from a list of objects which are displayed in detail in teh extension-panels, so i would need a few isExpanded for every expansion panel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay so the answer for this little troublemaker is that i didn't used trackBy in ng-for. trackBy enables angular to keep track of the elements iterated over in the loop, even if a new Object is delivered and thereby manages to keep the expansion panels state.

`identifyer = (index:number, item: any) => item.name;` and `<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let c of content; trackBy: identifyer">` seal the deal in the stackblitz example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49691295-qulg9d

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to keep your expanded panel id in a variable, and use it to with the `expanded` input parameter.

```
<mat-expansion-panel id="panelA" [expanded]="expandedPanel === 'panelA'">
```

[You can find a running example here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49691295)

Edit :
You should keep your panels expansion states somewhere, [here is a suggestion with an edit of your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49691295-2).

Comment: this sadly does not represent my use case, but i forked your stackblitz to mybe get it more clear. It actually misses real ngrx setup as i don't have that much of a lunch break to implement it right now

Comment: Somehow i didn't mind using objets that way to reference to the fields ids, this should work. Now i am curios if i should safe this into my ngrx store, as its part of the applications state. But driving me even more crazy is, that we have a case where this works without the additional variables